# Fermi's Lagrangian of the electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, tensor-calculus

Assume the Lorenz gauge is satisfied, that is $$\partial_\mu A^\mu=0.$$ I have to show that the Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{em} = -\frac{1}{8 \pi} \partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu$$

is equivalent to Fermi's Lagrangian

$$ \mathcal{L}_\mathrm{em}^F- \frac{1}{16 \pi} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{8 \pi} \lambda \left(\partial_\mu A^{\mu} \right)^2$$

when $\lambda=1$. I think the strategy consists in showing that the difference between the two Lagrangians is a divergence term, which has no effect on the equations of motion. However, I am quite not sure how to do that. Could you help me?

Comment: Quite funny. As far as I remember, Fermi's Lagrangian density is what you wrote as $$\mathcal{L}_{\mbox{em}}$$

Comment: Well, in that case I apologize. I probably got confused with the names.  Anyway, how could I show their equivalence?